# Helmholtz-Hodge decomposition

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

I have a question regarding a decomposition of a vector field.  So fix $ 1<p<\infty$ and let $ \Omega$ denote a smooth bounded domain in $ R^N$.   Now let $ F $ denote a smooth vector field $F:\Omega \rightarrow R^N$ with $ \|F\|_{L^p}=1$.     Now consider $\Delta \phi =div(F)$ in $\Omega$ with $ \phi=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.

My question is: does there exist some $C_p$ (independent of $F$ and $ \phi$) such that $ \| \nabla \phi \|_{L^p} \le C_p$?

When $p=2$ this is fairly obvious.  Can one prove it for another range of $p$ by some interpolation or ???

My real question here is given $ F  \in L^p(\Omega, R^N)$ can we decompose $F= \nabla \phi +g$  where $ \phi$ is as above and $div(g)=0$ and where the projections define by $ F \mapsto \nabla \phi$ and $ F \mapsto g$ are continuous in $L^p$.

I was convinced at one point this was always true and I had easy proof...but now I not so sure.  I have tried googling Helmholtz and Hodge decomposition but i don't appear to be getting what i want.

thanks.

Comment: I think i managed to prove this result by first proving an interior regularity result and then on $B_2^+$  by using an odd reflection of $ \phi$ (say $ \psi$ and then $ \Delta \psi=div(G)$) where $G^i$ for $1 \le i \le N-1$ is the odd reflection of $F^i$ and then $G^N(x)= G(x', - x_N)$ for $ x_N<0$ ...   does seem like a possible valid approach (I am more interested in whether the result is true as compared to whether by approach is correct) thanks

Comment: Look at the Theorem 1 in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123685710671

When the boundary is $C^1$ it says that your $\phi\in W^{1,p}$. The boundedness of another projection will follow by the triangle inequality.

Comment: @almaz.  Thanks a bunch for your comment. It really helps me.